# Android Heremaps Navigation SDK for Android Auto

Tags: android, heremaps, android-auto

I want to develop navigation app for Android auto using Heremap Navigation sdk. There is sample for just rendering the maps. Can anyone help me to implement navigation in Android Auto.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you explain what problems you face? The app should start with this template: https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/navigate/android/HelloMapAndroidAuto ... then you only need to combine it with VisualNavigator, ie. just start it and it will render guidance. Of course, you will need a lot of UI, too.